# How to get Next/Prev links to stay at sides of CarouFredSel slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, caroufredsel

I've been able to use CSS to make sure the NEXT and PREV links are in the correct position when you hover over an image. But if you go through the images on this page you'll notice that they don't display correctly with the landscape picture.

Is there another way with CSS or JS to create this effect and have it work with images of any width?

**Here is the related CSS:**

```
.image {
    display:table;
    padding:15px;
    border: 6px solid black;
    margin-top:100px;
}
.image img{
    height:430px;
}

.photoswrap {
    position:relative;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out; 
}
.caroufredsel_wrapper {
    
}
.tools ul {
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
    padding:0px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .1s ease-in-out; 
}
.tools li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;    
}
.tools li .next {
    margin-left: 128px;
}
.tools li .prev {
    margin-right: 128px;
}
.tools li a{
    font-family: 'Bold', 'BoldW';
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    margin:auto;
    border:5px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:14px;
    
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".photos").carouFredSel({
    width: "100%",
    
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        width: "variable",
        
    },
    scroll: {
        fx: "none",
        duration: 1
    },
    auto: {
        play: false,    
    },
    prev: {
        button: ".prev",
        key: "left"
    },
    next: {
        button: ".next",
        key: "right"
    },
    pagination: {
        container: ".pagination",
        keys: true
    },
    swipe: true,
    mousewheel: true
})
```

Comment: Could you get a jsfiddle going? It would be much easier to help you with one working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem your having is that the container photoswrap should be a wrap but it is a large container on the page. Remove all the CSS which adds width, height, padding or margin to elements contained within photoswrap except for the images (and left, right, top, bottom for absolute/relative elements).

Following this: 
- make the ul 100% width, 
- make sure photowrap is relative.

Finally you want:

```
.tools li .next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
.tools li .prev {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

This will be a much cleaner solution.